# pattern background text with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

How I can take value from a button and insert into a canvas to fill, for example if I press button T the box where is canvas will fill pattern with letter T entire box, I have an example but I don't want to copy the code I want to understand how it was made because I want to make something more advanced but I need to understand this first, here is the [link example of feature](https://www.theknitstudio.com.au/collections/personalised-blankets/products/cotton-personalised-bassinet-blanket).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I'm using 3 canvases. Two canvases are hidden but you don't need to attach them to the DOM. The logic is like this:

1. You have a first canvas (`canvas1`) where you draw the text from the `<textarea>`
2. You create a pattern using the `canvas1`: `ctx2.fillStyle = ctx2.createPattern(canvas1,"repeat-x");` and you use it to fill a second canvas `canvas2`. This second canvas is twice as wide as the main `canvas`.
3. You use the `canvas2` as a background image for the main `canvas` Here you may use a loop. I didn't.

```js
let fontSize = 50;
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
const canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");

test.appendChild(canvas1);// you don't need to attach this to the DOM
test.appendChild(canvas2);// you don't need to attach this to the DOM
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = fontSize * 4;
canvas1.height = fontSize;
canvas2.height = fontSize;
canvas2.width = 2*canvas.width;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
let ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

ctx1.font = fontSize+"px 'Lucida Console', monospace";

        
theText.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  ctx2.clearRect(0,0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  let _text = theText.value.toUpperCase();

  let textLength = ctx1.measureText(_text).width;
  canvas1.width = textLength || 1;// to avoid width 0 of the canvas
  ctx1.font = fontSize+"px 'Lucida Console', monospace";
  ctx1.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx1.textBaseline="middle"; 
  ctx1.fillText(_text, 0, canvas1.height/2);
  
  ctx2.fillStyle = ctx2.createPattern(canvas1,"repeat-x");
  
  ctx2.fillRect(0,0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
  
  ctx.drawImage( canvas2, 0, 0 );
  ctx.drawImage( canvas2, -canvas2.width/2, fontSize );
  ctx.drawImage( canvas2, canvas2.width/2, fontSize );
  ctx.drawImage( canvas2, 0, 2*fontSize );
  ctx.drawImage( canvas2, -canvas2.width/2, 3*fontSize );
  ctx.drawImage( canvas2, canvas2.width/2, 3*fontSize );
})
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
#test{display:none}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<textarea id="theText"></textarea>
<div id="test"></div>
```

In order to understand better what happens please delete `#test{display:none}` from the css. I hope this helps.

Comment: you`re amazing, can u pm me or to get contact with you?

Comment: Your example no longer works. Maybe support was deprecated?